# Why does java have types? Do they do anything at runtime?

Tags: java, types, casting

I was recently learning Objective C, and learnt that in Objective C, you can run a method on an object, even if it's Type does not declare it. I was wondering why you can't do that in Java.

For example:

```
class Animal{

public void move(){/*something*/}
}

class Dog extends Animal{

public void bark(){/*barks*/}
}

//In another class:
Animal anInstanceOfADog = new Dog();
anInstanceOfADog.bark()// <- This would be an error, as Animal doesn't have the method bark.
```

In this case, we would get an error as Animal cannot bark. Nonetheless, the object is a reference a Dog, and a Dog can bark.

Thus, the question is: What role do types play in the execution of code in Java? Why is this so?

Thanks,

Dean

Comment: This is a simple polymorphism question. Any book on Java can explain it. Or just search around Google.

Comment: first of all anInstanceOfADog.bark() give an error because the function is private, that has nothing to do with the class Animal

Comment: Java is "Type Safe". Here is a good place to start reading. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety

Comment: My Objective C is pretty basic, but as I understand it, you can "ask" that a method be executed on a given instance of an object, this does not guarantee that the execution will occur.  This is a lot like trying to do reflection calls in Java against unknown objects

Comment: @Baalthasarr thanks, changed to public. I wrote this on ipad :)

Comment: Oh sorry,I took it as C++!Extremely SORRY!

Comment: @MadProgrammer and lindon fox: Ok, in theory - would Java still be able to run without types?

Comment: @DeanLeitersdorf - No.. `Object` is also a type.. All methods belong to a type. Like MadProgrammer mentions, you could use reflection to *try* and call unrelated methods on a type. But you will eventually fail.

Comment: @DeanLeitersdorf I don't think Java would be Java without types...

Comment: With autoboxing you can treat everything as an Object, and with reflection you can do duck-typing. In short, you *can* do the same thing in Java; but the code isn't pretty.

Comment: @TheLostMind Not my question. I am asking whether Java can simply remove Types all-together (objects and primitive types alike) and still function

Comment: Try this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm

Comment: Even though the Dog instance barks, the Animal reference doesnt have a clue that is going to be referencing a Dog object at runtime, it only knows that its an Animal type, so the compiler complains if you try and call a method that doesnt exist in Animal. Its simple polymorphism.

Comment: @ReveladorSac Here you go, from your link: "...at compile time, the compiler used mailCheck() in Employee to validate this statement. At run time, however, the JVM invokes mailCheck() in the Salary class" (Salary extends Employee, see link for rest). At runtime, the object doesn't care what it's type is! The type is only used for compiler errors in this case. My question is if there is any use for types during runtime, not compile time.

Comment: @EdwardM.B. Yes ofc it's a compile time error. Question is, do types play a role at runtime?

Comment: `At run time, however, the JVM invokes mailCheck() in the Salary class` How can you say it doesn't care about type at run time? Why would it invoke `Salary`'s implementation if it didn't care?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You are contradicting yourself. The JVM invokes the method from Salary class, even though the object it does this so is typed as Employee class... If it did care, it would invoke Employee -- the fact that it doesn't shows that it would have worked just the same if there would have been no type.

Comment: You're confusing compile time types and run time types and where each is used.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Hold on, there is compile time and runtime types?? Which is which

Comment: Given `Animal anInstanceOfADog = new Dog();`. The compile time type of the variable `anInstanceOfADog` is `Animal`. At run time, the run time type of the object referenced by the variable `anInstanceOfADog` is `Dog`.

Comment: The method `bark()` could not be allowed to be invoked on `anInstanceOfADog` because at runtime it may be referencing an object of type `Cat` (or whatever). Types provide these checks.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Cool, that's what I thought. The question can be rephrased to: What is the use of compile time typing. See the answer below.

Comment: @DeanLeitersdorf The answer to your last comment is basically the answer to "What is the use of static typing", and is the subject of a decently sized debate these days...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of questions here, so I'll try to break it down. For readers: *please* correct things and add things as necessary. Programming languages/theory/etc. are *not* my strong suit:

> Why does java have types?

The Wikipedia article on [type systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) gives a pretty good summary: reducing possible bugs in a computer program. A broader statement might be "The fundamental problem addressed by a type theory is to ensure that programs have meaning."

Typeless programming languages *are* possible, and allow any operation to be performed on any data. Examples include assembly and Forth ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language#Typed_versus_untyped_languages)). But I suppose Java was designed to have types as a safety measure and to help ensure correctness, among other reasons.

> ...and learnt that in Objective C, you can run a method on an object, even if it's Type does not declare it. I was wondering why you can't do that in Java.

Well, you *can*, as pointed out by MadProgrammer. You just have to use reflection to do it. And doing so might raise an exception.

The reason you can't call a method that doesn't exist for a type at compile time is because that's the way Java's type system works. The methods available to call for a particular reference is determined by the type of that reference, not by the type of the object the reference points to. This might have been intended to ensure some degree of correctness, and allowing arbitrary methods to be called on an object was possibly determined to allow enough bugs to not be beneficial.

> What role do types play in the execution of code in Java?

Ensuring that if the program compiles you have a certain guarantee that some parts of the program will not cause errors. Types also allow reflection and casting to be performed; without them, the program wouldn't have the necessary information to do so without additional work on the side of the programmer.

In addition, if I remember correctly the JVM uses types internally to help with virtual method dispatch. Each object contains a pointer to its class object, which holds a table referencing the bits of code making up the declared methods for that type. If the JITC doesn't inline the method, the vtable defined in the class object is used to determine what implementation should be executed by the runtime. Without types, I'd imagine objects would have to have to contain their methods, which I would imagine would cause some pretty severe code bloat.

> Why is this so?

By design, I suppose?

Comment: Ok! This is better! So basically typing is just for making it easier to detect bugs and increase clarity of code. So I'm guessing it means that Types don't play a role in commanding the JVM. Thanks, you answered my question :)

Comment: @DeanLeitersdorf I probably didn't even scratch the surface of the topic, to be honest, as I haven't gotten into the more theoretical parts of CS/language design. As pointed out near the bottom, types *can* be used by the JVM (and I'm going to update in a bit, because they *definitely* do play a role...)

Comment: Cool, looking forward to the update :)

Comment: @DeanLeitersdorf OK, finished. I really hope I didn't mess anything up...